# Unable to select dropdwon in imacros

Tags: drop-down-menu, imacros

in imacros for the below line system is not clicking the drop down values

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Select CONTENT=Select

Comment: Try to record this click in **Experimental event recording mode**.

Comment: no bro it is not working , same issue

Comment: Please help bro

Comment: You provided very limited info so that somebody can help you more.

Comment: Could you, please, provide us with the excerpt of the html code you are working with, or a direct link to the web-page?